# How to get the nearest date to a record date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data structure:

**Table A**:

```
ID  |  RequestNumber  |  Date
----+-----------------+-----------
 1  |      1          | 2017/09/27
 2  |      1          | 2018/06/02
```

**Table B**:

```
RequestNumber  |  Serial  |  Date
---------------+----------+-----------
     1         |    1     | 2017/09/27
     1         |    2     | 2017/09/27
     1         |    6     | 2018/06/03
     1         |    7     | 2018/06/03
     1         |    8     | 2018/06/03
```

As we can see the nearest date to the first row of `Table A` is 2017/09/27  in the `Table B` and the nearest date to the second row is 2018/06/03 in the `Table B`

So...

I need a query to have each row from `Table A` with all rows from `Table B` that is the nearest to the record from `Table A` (it means 2 records should be returned the first record and 3 records should be returned for the second record)

The expected result would be:

```
ID  |  RequestNumber  |  Serial  |  Date
----+-----------------+----------+------------
 1  |      1          |    1     | 2017/09/27
 1  |      1          |    2     | 2017/09/27
 2  |      1          |    6     | 2018/06/03
 2  |      1          |    7     | 2018/06/03
 2  |      1          |    8     | 2018/06/03
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I have no idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

This query will do what you want. It joins `TableA` to `TableB` on `RequestNumber` and then to a table of minimum `DATEDIFF` values between `TableB` and `TableA`, ensuring we only get the closest date in the result:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.RequestNumber, b.Serial, b.Date 
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON b.RequestNumber = a.RequestNumber
JOIN (SELECT a.ID AS ID, MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, b.Date, a.Date))) AS days
      FROM TableA a
      JOIN TableB b ON b.RequestNumber = a.RequestNumber
      GROUP BY a.ID) c  ON c.ID = a.ID AND c.days = ABS(DATEDIFF(day, b.Date, a.Date))
```

Output:

```
ID  RequestNumber   Serial  Date
1   1               1       27/09/2017 09:30:00
1   1               2       27/09/2017 09:30:00
2   1               6       03/06/2018 09:30:00
2   1               7       03/06/2018 09:30:00
2   1               8       03/06/2018 09:30:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=dd46f0f2e21cb7a6051b44c7746af5b5)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is using LEFT JOIN and DENSE_RANK(). I assume, that you want the nearest and greater than date:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (
   ID int,
   RequestNumber int,
   [Date] date
)
CREATE TABLE #TableB (
   RequestNumber int,
   Serial int,
   [Date] date
)
INSERT INTO #TableA (ID, RequestNumber, [Date])
VALUES
   (1, 1, '2017-09-27'),
   (2, 1, '2018-06-02')

INSERT INTO #TableB (RequestNumber, Serial, [Date])
VALUES
   (1, 1, '2017-09-27'),
   (1, 2, '2017-09-27'),
   (1, 6, '2018-06-03'),
   (1, 7, '2018-06-03'),
   (1, 8, '2018-06-03'),
   (1, 9, '2018-06-05'),
   (1, 10, '2018-06-07')

; WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 
      a.ID, 
      a.RequestNumber, 
      b.Serial, 
      b.[Date], 
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID, a.RequestNumber ORDER BY a.ID, a.RequestNumber, b.[Date]) AS rn
   FROM #TableA a
   LEFT JOIN #TableB b ON (a.RequestNumber = b.RequestNumber) AND (a.[Date] <= b.[Date])
)
SELECT
      ID, 
      RequestNumber, 
      Serial, 
      [Date]
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID, RequestNumber
```

Output:

```
ID  RequestNumber   Serial  Date
1   1   1   27/09/2017 00:00:00
1   1   2   27/09/2017 00:00:00
2   1   6   03/06/2018 00:00:00
2   1   7   03/06/2018 00:00:00
2   1   8   03/06/2018 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired though I dont think you have actually specified the lesser date term correctly for dates as seen from the desired output.

```
    Select * from table B
       left join table A
         on 
       B.requestNumber=A.requestNumber
         and B.date >=A.Date;
```

Comment: if you want id on the left side you can improve my above query to `select a.id, b.* .....`

Answer (score 0):

This is a great place to use lateral joins (the `apply` keyword):

```
select a.*, b.*
from tablea a cross apply
     (select top (1) with ties b.*
      from tableb b
      order by abs(datediff(day, a.date, b.date))
     ) b;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=920c8a8253c4b9ef42d231613ac9dd2b) is a db<>fiddle.